# Foreach for nested list in Java

Tags: java

I have hero dataset i want to show list with all heroes are durable is true and agile is true from this dataset

```
{
    "hero_code": 1,
    "hero_name": "Blood Seeker",
    "power": [
        {
            "skill": "Durable",
            "status": true
        },
        {
            "skill": "Agile",
            "status": true
        }
    ]
},
{
    "hero_code": 2,
    "hero_name": "Pudge",
    "power": [
        {
            "skill": "Durable",
            "status": true
        },
        {
            "skill": "Agile",
            "status": false
        }
    ]
},
{
    "hero_code": 3,
    "hero_name": "Necrophos",
    "power": [
        {
            "skill": "Durable",
            "status": true
        },
        {
            "skill": "Agile",
            "status": true
        }
    ]
}
```

this is what i do to achieve that

```
List<Hero> filteredList = new ArrayList<>;
data.getHeroList().forEach(hero-> {
hero.getpower().forEach(power-> {
    if (power.getSkill().contains("Durable") || power.getSkill().contains("Agile")) {
        if (power.getStatus() == true){
            filteredList.add(hero);
        }
    }
});
});
```

but why my filtered list end up with 6 data instead of 2 ?
could anyone give me some insight ?
Thanks

Comment: Are you adding a hero multiple times if they have multiple powers?

Comment: @QuantumWiz No, i expect to add only Blood Seeker and Necrophos into filteredList

Comment: @DeanWinchester Don't both of those heroes get added twice since they have two powers that match your condition (either "Durable" or "Agile")?

Comment: @QuantumWiz so should i change to && ? cuz when i did that there's no data added into my filtered list

Comment: @DeanWinchester I now made an attempt as an answer. Can you check if it works?

Comment: @DeanWinchester Is my answer clear or do you still have something you'd like to ask?

Answer (score 1):

Here's my attempt. Didn't check if it works.

```
List<Hero> filteredList = new ArrayList<>;
data.getHeroList().forEach(hero-> {
    boolean hasDurable = false;
    boolean hasAgile = false;
    hero.getpower().forEach(power-> {
        if (power.getSkill().contains("Durable") && power.getStatus()) {
            hasDurable = true;
        }
        if (power.getSkill().contains("Agile") && power.getStatus()) {
            hasAgile = true;
        }
    });
    if(hasDurable && hasAgile) {
        filteredList.add(hero);
    }
});
```